# Why thread_local variable write is much faster than non thread_local variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

I do some performance test about thread_local add op on Xeon, and find that thread_local write is almost 1.5x faster than non thread_local(just normal variable, not atomic) in multithread environment. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Just a guess: You need synchronization for non `thread_local` variables to avoid data races, but with `thread_local`, each thread has its own variable, so no need for synchronization.

Comment: I just simply want to test thread_local variable performance, so I don't use atomic or any way to prevent data race